# Getting a text from an Edit Box

Tags: c, winapi

I want to get the text entered in the edit box, it's like a password if i enter 'hello' the window shows up anyways, this is my code it's kinda simple but i just want to know how to fix it, when i press OK nothing happens.

```
case IDOK:
    // i've declared wchar_t buff[100] outside the function.
    GetWindowTextW(MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_EDIT), buff, 100); 
    if(buff == 'hello')
        EndDialog(hwnd, IDOK);
    break;
```

This is the edit box in the .rc file.

```
    LANGUAGE LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL
        IDD_LOGIN DIALOG 0, 0, 186, 95
        STYLE DS_3DLOOK | DS_CENTER | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_SHELLFONT | WS_CAPTION |
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP | WS_SYSMENU
        CAPTION "Dialog"
        FONT 8, "Ms Shell Dlg"
    {
        LTEXT           "Enter Password", 0, 52, 19, 75, 9, SS_LEFT, WS_EX_LEFT
        EDITTEXT        IDD_EDIT, 34, 33, 113, 17, ES_AUTOHSCROLL, WS_EX_LEFT
        PUSHBUTTON      "Cancel", IDCANCEL, 30, 65, 50, 14, 0, WS_EX_LEFT
        DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK", IDOK, 106, 65, 50, 14, 0, WS_EX_LEFT
    }
```

Comment: `GetWindowText` expects `HWND` parameter. It should be `GetWindowText(GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDD_EDIT), buff, 100)` or just `GetDlgItemText(...)`. The C compiler doesn't stop on these errors, unlike C++, but it should still throw plenty of warnings. Set the compiler option to maximum warnings, and resolve all the warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
if (buff=='hello')
```

try:

```
if (wcscmp(buff, L"hello") == 0 )
```

Comment: No it's not working :/ i'm gonna edit the Program gonna add all the function which contains the edit, i'm not sure it's getting the message from the edit box.

Comment: Done, fixed.
Changed getWindowText with GetDlgItemText, made a mistake,thanks!